# Service Fabric Status: Upgrade service unreachable

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I broke my service fabric cluster some how, now all it says is "Status: Upgrade service unreachable".

How do I find out what's wrong? My VMs are up but I can't access the SF Explorer, and the SF blade in the Azure portal contains no nodes!

I believe this has something to do with setting up the [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy). I have downloaded and modified the default 5VM template and added in the `reverseProxyEndpointPort` property, upon deploying the VM's I get this message

```
Starting deployment...
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:53:09 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets 'Default' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError",
        "message": "Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode' has reported failure for VM Extension
'Default_ServiceFabricNode' with terminal error code '1009' and error message: 'Enable failed for plugin (name:
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode, version 1.0.0.33) with exception Command
C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode\\1.0.0.33\\ServiceFabricExtensionHandler.exe of
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode has exited with Exit code: -532462766'"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
At C:\Users\User\Downloads\template\deploy.ps1:104 char:5
+     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGr ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [NewAzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

Comment: I also got stuck with same upgrade service unreachable state. De-allocating and restarting the VM resolved my issue. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257426/service-fabric-cluster-status-upgrade-service-unreachable/60586189#60586189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit:

Make sure that you deploy your template using VM size D2 or better. You can scale down after it succeeds.

original:

Use RDP to connect to one of the nodes. Check the event viewer for more information. There's a SF section there.

Try restarting the SF service and/or machines.

(What did you do to get it into this state?)

Comment: I was trying to set up the reverse proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy

I tried restarting the services etc, but they still failed. I deleted the resource group, downloaded the template and started from scratch trying to deploy it with the `reverseProxyEndpointPort` property. The deployment fails with the above error (edited question)

Comment: Haven't seen that one before. What Machine size are you using? Often deployment problems are caused by using machines that are too slow.

Comment: Standard_A0, perhaps that's why?

Comment: That must have been it, all set up and working now. Thanks ever so much for your help!

Comment: Tried a D2_V2, still was stuck. Used a D3_V2, which completed, then sized down afterwards.