# Service Fabric Cluster status "Upgrade service unreachable"

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I Had SF cluster made of 3 Standard A0 nodes.
I scaled cluster in to 1 node and understood that this was bad idea because nothing was working in this state (even SF explorer was not working)
Then I scaled it out back to 3 nodes and restarted Primary scaleser.
Now all nodes in scaleset are up and running but SF cluster status is "Upgrade service unreachable".
I saw similar question [Service Fabric Status: Upgrade service unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122677/service-fabric-status-upgrade-service-unreachable) where was recommended to scale nodes up to D2 but this hasn't solve my problem.
I have connected to one node via RDP and are some Event logs:

EventLog -> Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft Service Fabric -> Operational:

Node name: _SSService_0 has failed to open with upgrade domain: 0, fault domain: fd:/0, address: 10.0.0.4, hostname: SSService000000, isSeedNode: true, versionInstance: 5.6.210.9494:3, id: d9e8bae2d4d8116bfefb989b95e91f7b, dca instance: 131405546580494698, error: FABRIC_E_TIMEOUT

EventLog -> Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft Service Fabric -> Admin:

client-10.0.0.4:19000/10.0.0.4:19000: error = 2147943625, failureCount=487. Filter by (type~Transport.St && ~"(?i)10.0.0.4:19000") to get listener lifecycle. Connect failure is expected if listener was never started, or listener/its process was stopped before/during connecting.

Comment: From what I recall, only (without plenty of faffing around) solution is to destroy and recreate the cluster!

Comment: Running into the same error after scaling up. Recreating the cluster isn't enough, cause then the existing VMSS complains about a different cluster unique identifier mismatch. Gladly it is just a test environment cluster in azure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scaling down the cluster by resizing VM scale set to 1 you're basically destroying the cluster because it requires a minimum of 3 nodes by design. Therefore the only way is to recreate it again from scratch.

If you need a tiny cluster consisting of just 1 node (like for testing purposes) there is a way in Azure now to create a single node cluster, but you won't be able to scale it as it's a special case not for production use.

Comment: What If 2 of 3 vms from my cluster are going down for couple of minutes? are you saying this will ruin my cluster forever?

Comment: @Anubis Azure Service Fabric needs minimum 3 computers for "normal" operation as everything you do gets replicated at least 3 times. Saying that, if 1 node goes down for whatever reason you get a cluster health error event, however when it's up again there is enough data on the other 2 nodes to restore the failed node. There is no guarantee that if 2 nodes go down the third node can restore the cluster when they're up again, therefore for production I'd recommend 5 nodes minimum.

Comment: I do understand this. What I do not understand is why mu cluster is not working now when all 3 VM's are running.

Comment: this answer is not correct. fabric can run just as well on 1 node.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' no. 1 node cluster is a "hack" to pay less. This is not even a cluster of any kind.

Comment: Despite -1 on this answer this is still correct. If you're looking to hire the one who has put -1 to do anything other than simple scripting please don't.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade service unreachable** this happens if the number of active VM or node of the cluster become 0 anyhow. In my case, his happened by restarting all the VM at a time. In this state, the nodes are available and running but they have been disconnected from the cluster.

[image]

I **resolved** this, by deallocating and restarting the node from `Virtual machine Scale set`.
[image]