# Upgrade service unreachable status on service fabric Azure

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am somehow getting "Upgrade service unreachable" status for service fabric on Azure.And due to this behavior of my application is weird - sometime able to access and sometime not able to access.Also found no issues in virtual machine's event viewer.

I have restart the nodes(3 nodes) as well as restart virtual machines also.

I have also read from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade) but could not found anything.

Anyone have any idea why this could occur and how this status change?

Comment: After did lots of research I found that we need to create new cluster again.And also come to know that ASF is not mature enough for productions. https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/877

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122677/service-fabric-status-upgrade-service-unreachable/60586243#60586243

Answer (score 0):

I know this is two months late, but I found a resolution to this issue for myself, and it might be similar for you. There are two issues:

1. VM instance size: From my experience, you probably need at least Standard_D2s, depending on what applications you are running. The applications can overload the VMs and cause the upgrade service to fail.
2. Make sure your instance count matches the Service Fabric Reliability level. It should be "Bronze" for 3 nodes. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to update this in the portal (I don't think there is one) but you can do it through ARM templates or Azure Powershell/CLI. You can use the guide here for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#the-reliability-characteristics-of-the-cluster

Scaling up VM size and making sure the reliability level matched worked for me, I deployed ARM templates and eventually the upgrade service started functioning again.